# How to set backgroud color to BoxLayout in kivy?

Tags: python, background, kivy

I have BoxLayout in kivy

```
root = BoxLayout(
 orientation = "horizontal",
 padding = 1,
 background_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]
)
```

Unfortunately, the BoxLayout has a horrible background (default)

How can I set a custom background color for the BoxLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this you will get a `TypeError` as the class `BoxLayout` has no `background_color` property.

In kivy you are reasonably free to create your own widget graphical representation. For that you have to create a subclass inheriting from `BoxLayout` with the desired property.

Below is a sample example implemented with kivy lang, but you can do that in python also with some binding (that will be a little bit verbose).

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ColorProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout



Builder.load_string(
"""

<CustomRoot>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

""")



class CustomRoot(BoxLayout):
    background_color = ColorProperty() # The ListProperty will also work.


class MyApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return CustomRoot(background_color = (1, 0, 1, 1))

MyApp().run()
```

For more have a look at kivy documentation.